# minify Javascript code for showing and hiding lots of data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Script :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#finance").hide();
    $("#HR").hide();

    var slz = jQuery('#specialization');
    var select = this.value;
    slz.change(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == '2') {
            $('#finance').show();
            $('#HR').hide();
        }
        if ($(this).val() == '3') {
            $('#HR').show();
            $('#finance').hide();
        }
        if ($(this).val() == '1') {
            $('#finance').hide();
            $('#HR').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

HTML :

```
<select name="specialization" id="specialization">
 <option value="1" id="1">select specialization</option>
 <option value="2" id="2">Finance</option>
 <option value="3" id="3">Human Resource</option>
 <option value="4" id="4">Information Technology</option>
 <option value="5" id="5">Marketing</option>
 <option value="6" id="6">Material Management</option>
 <option value="7" id="7">Operations</option>
 <option value="8" id="8">Supply Chain Management</option>
</select>
<div id="specialization_subjects">
    Specialization Subjects
</div>
<ul id="finance">
 <li>Financial Institution & Services</li>
 <li>International Financial Management</li>
 <li>Working Capital Management</li>
 <li>Project Work</li>
</ul>
<ul id="HR">
 <li>Financial Institution & Services HR</li>
 <li>International Financial Management</li>
 <li>Working Capital Management</li>
 <li>Project Work</li>
</ul>
```

Hi every one I have given my javascript and html code for showing and hiding the ul according to the selected dropdown value.. this code works for me fine..but i wanted to minify the javascript file ..because I have lots of ul and lots of drop down..

I wanted to remove the if else condition and wanted to use for loop for this to work by storing values in arrays etc..

Thanks In advance Please Help

Comment: nodejs has a package called `minify` (https://npmjs.org/package/minify) of course you'll need node running on your machine to use it.  There is also an online "minifier" called JSCompress: http://jscompress.com/

Comment: I think you mean "shorten", not "minify". "Minify" has a completely different meaning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to assume you're not asking to *minify*, but to *minimize* your code and make it more efficient.  And since you say you have lots of data, and your option shows 8 choices while your code only deals with 2, I'm going to show you a way to handle your option selection easily.

(This assumes you can change the HTML.  If you can't, please make that clear.)

First, add a common class to all the uls you want to deal with, and add a data attribute matching the option value

```
<ul id="finance" class="dropDownOption" data-optionValue="2">
 <li>Financial Institution & Services</li>
 <li>International Financial Management</li>
 <li>Working Capital Management</li>
 <li>Project Work</li>
</ul>
<ul id="HR" class="dropDownOption" data-optionValue="3">
 <li>Financial Institution & Services HR</li>
 <li>International Financial Management</li>
 <li>Working Capital Management</li>
 <li>Project Work</li>
</ul>
```

Then your `slz.change` function becomes *much* easier and more robust:

```
slz.change(function () 
{
    $(".dropDownOption").hide();
    $("ul[data-optionValue='" + this.value + "']").show();
}
```

Without modifying your markup, you can do some things, but they're riskier.  *With the markup you've shown*, it's safe to just use `$("ul").hide()`, though if you haven't shown us all of it, that could be dangerous.  For handling the value to the id, you would need a conversion function:

```
function convertValueToId(value) {
    switch (value) {
        case 1: return; // empty return, since this one is the "unselected" case
        case 2: return "finance";
        case 3: return "HR";
        // etc
    }
}
slz.change(function() {
    $("ul").hide();
    var id = convertValueToId(this.value);
    if (id) {
        $("#" + id).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: This works great for me..thank you very much @Scott Mermelstein Sir

Comment: Glad to be of help. :-)

Answer (score 0):

you can use `switch case` instead of `if else`

Comment: I wanted to remove the if else condition and wanted to use for loop for this to work by storing values in arrays etc..